# ListView Checkbox list not registering checks

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I have a ListView with a list of checkable elements. Multiple elements can be checked. I did this to try to check which boxes were ticked:

```
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")

public class ListOfMajors extends Activity {
    public static boolean aerospace, agricultural, biomed, chem, civil, computer, electrical, physics, environment, industrial, materials, mechanical;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.majorslist);
        ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.majorslist);
        String[] list={"Aerospace Engineering","Agricultural Engineering","Biomedical Engineering","Chemical Engineering","Civil Engineering",
                        "Computer Engineering","Electrical Engineering","Engineering Physics","Environmental Engineering","Industrial Engineering",
                        "Materials Engineering","Mechanical Engineering"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListOfMajors.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);
        mylist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

        SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = mylist.getCheckedItemPositions();
        if (checkedItems!= null){
            for(int i=0; i<checkedItems.size();i++){
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(0)){
                    aerospace = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(1)){
                    agricultural = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(2)){
                    biomed = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(3)){
                    chem = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(4)){
                    civil = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(5)){
                    computer = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(6)){
                    electrical = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(7)){
                    physics = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(8)){
                    environment = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(9)){
                    industrial = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(10)){
                    materials = true;
                }
                if(checkedItems.valueAt(11)){
                    mechanical = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Is this code the correct way to accomplish this? My application is not doing what I intended to do elsewhere in the application and was wondering whether this would be the problem. If so, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have an `OnItemClickListener`

```
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(this);



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int pos, long arg3)
{

switch (pos){
    case 0:
    aerospace = true;
    break;
    case 1:
    agricultural = true;
    break;
    ......etc
}


}
```

Comment: Which part of the class should I put this in?

Comment: Main. In your case ListOfMajors

Comment: When I put the mylist.setOnItemClickListener(this); in, I get and error saying:The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (ListOfMajors)

Comment: Try implementing `OnItemClickListener` class declaration like: `public class ListOfMajors extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener`